# Critical number $y = \frac{1}{x^2 + 2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Seems pretty straight forward but my book seems to be giving an incorrect answer without any explanation to their magic.

$$y = \frac{1}{x^2 + 2}$$

I know that this has no 0 so that rule of finding a critical number can be discarded.

$$y = (x^2 + 2)^{-1}$$

$$y' = -1(x^2 + 2)^{-2}\cdot 2x$$

$$y' = \frac{-2x}{(x^2 + 2)^{2}}$$

So now I am not so sure how my book got c = 0.

Comment: Note that to find the critical numbers of $y$, you must set $y'$ equal to $0$. Setting $y$ equal to $0$ will only give you the $x$-intercepts. (Also, you need to check where $y$ is not differentiable, but since the denominator is always nonzero, this step can be skipped.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$y' = \frac{-2x}{(x^2+2)^2}$$

Critical points occur if and when there are values of $x$ which make  ***derivative*** of the function equal to zero. (I.e., you find the "zeros" of the function, if any.)

You also check for points at which the function is not differentiable. The denominator in both the function $y$ and the derivative $y'$ are defined (and positive) for all real numbers: The denominator $(x^2 + 2)^2 \gt 0$ for all $x$.

So here, the only points we need to consider are the zeros of the derivative.

In this case, $\;y' = 0 \iff $ the numerator is **zero**. 
The numerator is zero if and only if $$-2x = 0 \iff x = 0$$ 
So there is indeed a critical point when $x = 0$, with the point being $(x,y) =  (0, 1/2)$.

Comment: Looks good - TU +1

Comment: @amWhy: May I ask you a question in English Amy?

Comment: @Babak Yes, of course!

Comment: Thanks. Assume you are proposing a Theorem in your paper. In one part of the proof, we have some basics approach which the reader can find them by himself. So, in this part of proof you want to avoid saying some neglectable points. In fact you want to make the long story short. Please, have a look at this sentence and tell me is it good and formal? And if you have any suggestions please inform me kindly. This is that sentence: "To shorten the proof and to avoid of being talkativeness, we consider two cases for $i$...."

Comment: How about "To shorten the proof and avoid excessive exposition, we consider two cases for $i$..."

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks so much. I feel this is much better. :-)

Comment: You're welcome, dear @Babak!

Answer (score 1):

In your second line you have that the derivative is

$$\frac{-2x}{(x^2+2)^{2}}$$

which is 0 when x=0 so it is a critical point of this function. In the third line you omitted the x in the derivative.

Comment: Oh, so I probably need to factor all these problems.

Answer (score 1):

A fraction is zero only if the numerator is zero and the denominator is not.  The denominator, $(x^2+2)^2$, is never zero no matter what number $x$ is.  So the question is: what must $x$ be in order that the numerator, $-2x$, be zero?  In other words, how to solve this equation for $x$:
$$
-2x=0.
$$
Divide both sides by $-2$:
$$
x = \frac{0}{-2}.
$$
Now the problem is: what do you get when you divide $0$ by $-2$?